# Send-MailMessage in Scheduled Task has wrong encoding

Tags: powershell, encoding

I use the following script to send two E-Mails to different people:

```
# Datum von nächstem Samstag ermitteln
$Date = Get-Date "18:00"
while ($Date.DayOfWeek -ne "Saturday") { $date = $date.AddDays(1) }

# UTF-8 Encoding
$utf8 = New-Object System.Text.utf8encoding

# E-Mail Benachrichtigung zusammenstellen
$EmailNotifications = @{

    AlleMAEmail = @{
        From = "xy"
        To = "xy"
        Subject = "Serverarbeiten Update Installation $($Date.DateTime)"
        Body = "abc äöü"
    }

    ITAdminEmail = @{
        From = "xy"
        To = "xy"
        Subject = "Bitte bei XY Updates genehmigen & Ablehnen"
        Body = "abc äöü"
    }

}

# E-Mails versenden.
$EmailNotifications.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    $splat = $_.Value
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "xy" -BodyAsHtml -Encoding $utf8 @splat
}
```

This works when I run the code in Visual Studio Code, however I need a scheduled task on a server to run this. When the scheduled task runs the script, it can't handle the umlauts in the mail body, e.g it sends `ü` as `Ã¼`

How can I fix this? I already specified my encoding

This is how my task is set up:

- Start a Program: `PowerShell`
- Arguments: `-Command "& '\\server\path\script.ps1'" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass`

**Edit:** I noticed that the PowerShell that gets started is the "old" PowerShell which has a black background. Could this be the problem? How to start the new one?

Comment: This indicates that either the Powershell already reads the source code with the wrong encoding, or that the source file is not saved in the right encoding. As a first step, make sure your editor saves the ps1 file as UTF-8 with BOM and see if that already helps.

Comment: @Tomalak well that was easy! Thank you. First I had to set the `files.encoding` setting in Visual Studio Code to `utf8bom`. Then save my script again, by clicking the encoding button on the bottom of the editor and choose `Save with encoding`, `UTF-8 Bom`

Comment: @Tomalak if you care for 35 additional reputation (even though you got so much already!) you could expand this to an answer and i'll gladly accept it. Otherwise I will answer my own post until Thursday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell interprets the source code of your .ps1 file when it reads it, but not necessarily in the encoding you expect.

When you save a file as UTF-8, but PowerShell's default is Windows-1252, then `ü` becomes `Ã¼` before your code even runs. `Send-MailMessage` then correctly encodes `Ã¼` into UTF-8 and so these characters are retained in the email. When you run the program from within Visual Studio Code, different defaults apply and the outcome is different.

I don't think there is a command line switch that forces PowerShell to interpret script files in a certain encoding, but you can help the encoding auto-detection along by prefixing your file with a byte-order mark (BOM).

A BOM is mandatory for UTF-16 (that is what's commonly called "Unicode" encoding in various Microsoft tools), but optional in UTF-8. UTF-8 BOMs are wrong for many use cases, so VS Code defaults to "UTF-8 without BOM". When you explicitly save the file as "UTF-8 with BOM" then Powershell will infer the correct encoding when reading the script.

There is a way to configure VS Code to pick specific encodings per file type, you could set it to always save .ps1 files as UTF-8 with BOM.

The alternative would be to save the file as Windows-1252, which would match PowerShell's expectation on your machine, but might break on different computers (or when run from within VS Code).